# delete .svn files with Phing (or Ant)

Tags: php, ant, build, phing

How would I script .svn files removal with Phing...
I'm trying this target but it doesn't seem to work.
My ${site.dir} variable is "./../../.."

```
 92         <!-- Cleanup the project directory from any junk files: .svn, .hg etc-->
 93         <target name="cleanup">
 94                     <echo msg="Site dir ${site.dir}"/>
 95             <delete>
 96                 <fileset dir="${site.dir}">     
 97                     <include name="*.svn" />        
 98                     <include name="**/*.svn" />     
 99                     <include name="*.hg" />         
100                     <include name="**/*.hg" />      
101                 </fileset>
102             </delete>
103         </target>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well. this exec calls do the job:

```
<target name="cleanup">
    <echo msg="Site dir ${site.dir}"/>
    <exec command="find ${site.dir} -name .svn -delete" />
    <exec command="find ${site.dir} -name .hg -delete" />
</target>
```

However - can someone explain why original script didn't work?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok. resolved.
apparantly I needed to add trailing slash to indictaed that .svn is a directory.
This works:

```
92         <!-- Cleanup the project directory from any junk files: .svn, .hg etc-->
 93         <target name="cleanup">
 94            <!-- <echo msg="Site dir ${site.dir}"/>
 95             <exec command="find ${site.dir} -name .svn -delete" />
 96             <exec command="find ${site.dir} -name .hg -delete" />
 97             -->
 98             <delete includeemptydirs="true">
 99                 <fileset dir="${site.dir}" defaultexcludes="false" casesensitive="false">
100                     <include name="*.svn/" />
101                     <include name="**/*.svn/" />
102                     <include name="*.hg/" />
103                     <include name="**/*.hg/" />
104                 </fileset>
105             </delete>
106 
107         </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd just use the SvnExport (or equivalent) task to make a clean version of your project.